# What's a simple way to log a programming error in node?

Tags: node.js, q

**NOTE: I edited this question to more accurately show the problem, rather than delete and rewrite it.  Hope that's OK.**

For the following code:

```
var Q = require('q');

function first (){
  var d = Q.defer();

  setTimeout(function(){
    d.resolve([]);
  }, 1000);

  return d.promise;
}

function second(v){
  sdf;
  console.log("hi")
}

first()
.then(second);
```

How can I determine that there is a `ReferenceError` in there?  Is the only option to add a second function argument in the `then` call?

Even though it's not recommended, I tried using `process.on('uncaughtException')` but to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: What happened when you tried to use `process.on('uncaughtException')`?

Comment: @laggingreflex nothing happens, but I realize there are some things I neglected to mention in my question -- namely this is taking place _outside_ of the main thread.

Comment: That's because `Q` catches this exeption. As you just use `.then` without a fail calback that error is _lost_ (your promise chain is not complete, as you neither call `done` on it nor handling the error case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your final call like this:

```
function errorHandler(err) {
  console.log('You had an error, ' + err);
}

first
  .then(second, errorHandler);
```

The promise captures any exceptions that throw within it, you need to explicitly handle it.

A variation that's q specific would be:

```
first
  .then(second)
  .fail(errorHandler);
```

You may consider this easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be appropriate to catch the error before the declaration of the `contract` object. So something like this:

```
map(locations, function(loc) {
    if(!loc.ClientId) {
        console.log("Error: loc.ClientId is undefined");
    } else {
        var contract = {
            "clientName": clients[loc.ClientId][0]
        }
        ...
    }
})
```

Here the error is logged to console when `loc.ClientId` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what your stack trace looks like. If you're using express or restify, for example, you may actually need to listen for the `uncaughtException` event on your `server` object. The error is normally not lost; put something like this into a sample JS file:

```
null.f();
```

and you'll see a TypeError thrown, as you are expecting.

If you're not sure of the stack, log it:

```
console.log(new Error("this is my stack").stack);
```